# creating a user and granting no privileges

Tags: mysql, sql, privileges

Is there a difference between

```
grant usage on databasename.* to 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'password'
```

and

```
grant usage on *.* to 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'password'
```

and

```
create user 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'password'
```

assuming that the user does not already exist?  My understanding is that each of these creates a user with a password, and grants no privileges to the user.

If the user does already exist, then I expect some differences:

- the `grant`-statements will change the password to 'password'
- the `create user`-statement will fail with an error

Answer (score 3):

All these statements do the same - they create new user without any privileges.
First and second do it using GRANT statement, where USAGE means - NO PRIVILEGES.

But there is a difference between GRANT+USAGE and CREATE USER statements:

```
grant usage on *.* to 'username1'@'localhost'; -- when password is not specified
```

will throw an error in case of NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER sql mode.

From the reference - NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER Prevent GRANT from automatically creating new users if it would otherwise do so, unless a non-empty password also is specified.

You are right about the GRANT and CREATE USER statements when user exists; CREATE USER will throw an error, but in this case, if you want to change the password, you can use [SET PASSWORD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-password.html) statement, e.g. -

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'username'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('new password');
```